# Debian stretch - update broken - seems buggy dpkg

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I saw [Debian Jessie - dpkg / apt intall, update and uninstall broken](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233501/debian-jessie-dpkg-apt-intall-update-and-uninstall-broken) and unlike that one, python is well and good herein.

```
[$] ls -l /usr/bin/python

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jun  3 20:09 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

There are 3-4 packages which are making updates/upgrades on the system next to impossible.

```
[$] sudo dpkg --audit cme libconfig-model-perl libconfig-model-dpkg-perl fonts-arphic-uming
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 cme                  Check or edit configuration data with Config::Model
 fonts-arphic-uming   (no description available)
 libconfig-model-dpkg-perl editor for Dpkg source files with validation
 libconfig-model-perl module for describing and editing configuration data

The following packages are missing the list control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 fonts-arphic-uming   (no description available)

The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 fonts-arphic-uming   (no description available)
```

Trying to reinstall the packages via aptitude I get this -

```
[$] sudo aptitude reinstall cme libconfig-model-perl libconfig-model-dpkg-perl fonts-arphic-uming
                              
The following packages will be REINSTALLED:
  cme fonts-arphic-uming libconfig-model-dpkg-perl libconfig-model-perl 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
E: Can't find a source to download version '2.092-1' of 'libconfig-model-perl:amd64'
After unpacking 0 B will be used.
E: Can't find a source to download version '2.092-1' of 'libconfig-model-perl:amd64'
E: Internal error: couldn't generate list of packages to download
```

Forgot to share that I had already downloaded the `libconfig-model-perl` binary package from `snapshots.debian.org` and tried installing it, got the following -

```
[$] sudo dpkg -i libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb

[sudo] password for shirish: 
D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
D000001: ensure_statoverrides: new, (re)loading
(Reading database ... 1205324 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb ...
D000001: process_archive oldversionstatus=broken due to postinst failure
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: version '2.075-2~' is not valid
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: version '2.075-2~' is not valid
dpkg: error processing archive libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: version '2.070-1~' is not valid
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
D000001: cmpversions a='0:2016.03.30' b='0:2016.05.24' r=-2
D000001: cmpversions a='0:1.18.14' b='0:1.16' r=2
D000001: cmpversions a='0:1.18.14' b='0:1.16' r=2
D000001: cmpversions a='0:1.18.14' b='0:1.16' r=2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb
```

I am nonplussed, can somebody help?

My sources.list -

```
[$] cat /etc/apt/sources.list

 #### testing #########
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free

 #### unstable #########
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib 

 #### experimental #########
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib 
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib

 ##### Debug packages #######
deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ testing-debug main
deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ unstable-debug main
deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ experimental-debug main
```

DPkG version -

```
[$] apt-cache policy dpkg
                 
dpkg:
  Installed: 1.18.14
  Candidate: 1.18.14
  Version table:
     1.18.15 1
          1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.18.14 600
        600 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

On Stephen's advice did the following -

```
[$] sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libconfig-model-perl.prerm
```

and tried to install the old package -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~] - [5108]
└─[$] sudo dpkg -i libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb

D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
D000001: ensure_statoverrides: new, (re)loading
(Reading database ... 1205324 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb ...
D000001: process_archive oldversionstatus=broken due to postinst failure
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: version '2.070-1~' is not valid
dpkg: error processing archive libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: version '2.075-2~' is not valid
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
D000001: cmpversions a='0:2016.03.30' b='0:2016.05.24' r=-2
D000001: cmpversions a='0:1.18.14' b='0:1.16' r=2
D000001: cmpversions a='0:1.18.14' b='0:1.16' r=2
D000001: cmpversions a='0:1.18.14' b='0:1.16' r=2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb
```

Any more ideas anybody?

Searching for broken packages shows nothing -

```
[$] alias aptb 

aptb='aptitude search '\''~b'\'
```

And the search -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~] - [5109]
└─[$] aptb
              
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~] - [5110]
```

This shouldn't happen, right?

I had already turned on dpkg-debug as can be seen -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~] - [4998]
└─[$] cat /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg

# dpkg configuration file
#
# This file can contain default options for dpkg.  All command-line
# options are allowed.  Values can be specified by putting them after
# the option, separated by whitespace and/or an `=' sign.
#
debug=1

# Do not enable debsig-verify by default; since the distribution is not using
# embedded signatures, debsig-verify would reject all packages.
no-debsig

# Log status changes and actions to a file.
log /var/log/dpkg.log
```

but still did do as Stephen asked -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~] - [5126]
└─[$] su -
                                 
Password: 

root@debian:~# DPKG_DEBUG=1 dpkg -i libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb': No such file or directory

root@debian:~# pwd
/root

root@debian:~# cd /home/shirish

root@debian:/home/shirish# DPKG_DEBUG=1 dpkg -i libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb

D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
D000001: ensure_statoverrides: new, (re)loading
(Reading database ... 1205324 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb ...
D000001: process_archive oldversionstatus=broken due to failed removal or installation
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: version '2.070-1~' is not valid
dpkg: error processing archive libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: version '2.075-2~' is not valid
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
D000001: cmpversions a='0:2016.03.30' b='0:2016.05.24' r=-2
D000001: cmpversions a='0:1.18.14' b='0:1.16' r=2
D000001: cmpversions a='0:1.18.14' b='0:1.16' r=2
D000001: cmpversions a='0:1.18.14' b='0:1.16' r=2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb
```

With the old version of dpkg, the packages were able to install and show no issues -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~] - [5168]
└─[$] sudo dpkg --audit cme libconfig-model-perl libconfig-model-dpkg-perl fonts-arphic-uming
                                        
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~] - [5169]
```

I am going to keep it open for a day just in case something untoward happens. Meanwhile, I will upgrade everything except `dpkg` and do that at the very last.

Comment: Are you sure about you didn't mixed Debian repositories with something other?

Comment: Am using stretch, do have some very limited from experimental and maybe (just maybe) 1-2 packages from contrib, otherwise it's mostly a stretch based.

Comment: Ohh... Don't use packages from experimental! If you are careful you can manually edit /var/lib/dpkg/status. Make backup and be careful! Everything is repairable.

Comment: @IporSircer experimental isn't a default installation candidate (like backports), so packages aren't picked from there unless explicitly asked for.

Comment: @shirish what version of `dpkg` do you have?

Comment: correct, for packages for installation from experimental I have to give version details such as `$ sudo aptitude install atop=2.2.4-1~exp1` in order to install from experimental

Comment: @StephenKitt I am using dpkg 1.8.14, the one in testing. Have also updated the question with those details as well.

Comment: @IporSircer I had intuited that I may have to fiddle around with the status file or maybe at `/var/lib/dpkg/info` as well. Don't worry, I am a patient person, looking to Stephen to share some of his wisdom so I know the way forward.

Comment: Edit your sourcrs.list , replace `http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/` with the nearest mirorr (other than httpredir), sometimes it can be buggy

Comment: @GAD3R I think that's the wrong road to take. Except for few situations, httpredir has actually improved as there is no single point of failure which is with a mirror. I just did an apt update to show how it is https://paste.debian.net/896413/ . I just cannot take the opportunity due to the issue outlined above.

Comment: That is very strange... Could you become `root`, and run `DPKG_DEBUG=1 dpkg -i libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb`? That should show the `dpkg-maintscript-helper` debug output which might help.

Comment: Have updated my question with what you have asked/shared.

Comment: OK... Here's something else you can try: downgrade `dpkg` to [version 1.18.10](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/dpkg/1.18.10/#dpkg_1.18.10), just before the version checks were introduced. Then reinstall `libconfig-model-perl` yet again!

Comment: That worked - https://paste.debian.net/896452/ , I actually downgraded all the dpkg packages to 1.8.10 and it worked  all smoothly. aptb didn't show anything broken.

Comment: @StephenKitt - while managed to resolve it thanx to you, as have shared will be upgrading things one by one (along with their dependencies) .  Let's see if things go smoothly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try reinstalling from [snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/); you'll find the appropriate version of [`libconfig-model-perl`](http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/libconfig-model-perl/) there:

```
wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20160924T233848Z/pool/main/libc/libconfig-model-perl/libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb
```

Given the `dpkg-maintscript-helper` errors you're getting, with a current version of `dpkg`, there's probably something else badly messed up. To get `libconfig-model-perl` reinstalled, delete the `prerm` script and reinstall the package:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libconfig-model-perl.prerm
sudo dpkg -i libconfig-model-perl_2.092-1_all.deb
```

If that doesn't work, you can try downgrading `dpkg` itself to [version 1.18.10](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/dpkg/1.18.10/#dpkg_1.18.10), which is the last version released before the failing version checks were introduced. Once you've done that, try reinstalling `libconfig-model-perl` yet again — the version checks won't fail, and the maintainer scripts should complete without any other difficulties.

Once that's done, try `aptitude reinstall ...` again and if necessary, reinstall any other missing package from snapshots.

Comment: @skitt I updated my question with the answer you gave.

Comment: @shirish there's something weird going on here, try deleting the `prerm` script (see my updated answer).

Comment: I deleted and tried to install but got the same result. Have updated my question with the same procedure.

Comment: @skitt could you update your answer with the bit about downgrading to the earlier version of dpkg. I feel that is the real fix as it seems 'version checking' or whatever 'feature' the dpkg developers are trying to bring in is buggy atm. I would be in a position to accept your answer with the updated dpkg bits. Thank you for sharing your wisdom.

Comment: @shirish done, and you're welcome! I don't understand why the checks would fail though, the behaviour you got is really very strange...